# Where to find the Dynamics CRM Plugin Registration Tool Source Code?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-365

I am looking for the Dynamics CRM Plugin Registration Tool Source Code. Any idea from where I can download it please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source code of the latest version is not made available by Microsoft.

You can find the source code of the Plugin Registration Tool for XrmToolBox (based from the CRM 2011 SDK Plugin Registration Tool) here :

https://github.com/Innofactor/PluginRegistration